# Private org wide setting and Duplicates

Tags: visualforce, permissions, account

I need Sales reps to be able to see or search for accounts/contacts owned by other reps before they create new ones or convert a lead.
Problem is our Org wide security setting is set to Private and its causing many duplicates. Is there a solution to this without having to make Accounts public?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple options available for that purpose

1. You can use standard Salesforce Duplicate rule feature which was introduced recently by Salesforce. It has option to bypass the sharing rules but it has following limitation

> Bypass sharing rules: The matching rule compares all records,
>   regardless of user access, but the resulting list of possible
>   duplicates includes only records the user has access to.

[image]

2. You can install [Dupcatcher](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IYLlEAO) (A app exchange listed app)
3. You can write your own logic inside the trigger (before insert) and throw an error message once duplicate record found with record name.
4. You can create one visualforce page with controller (Make controller without sharing which will run that in system administrator context) and allow user to search a record by name, last name or other filter criteria prior to create new record.

Comment: fantatic.... :)